# Gitlab CE https on port 8090

Tags: ssl, gitlab

I have a big problem securing my Gitlab CE using SSL.

I've tried many tutorials and now I have the following status:
with `external_url='http://example.com:8090' everything works fine.
If I change`external_url='https://example.com:8090' I can't access Gitlab.

My gitlab.rb file has been changed according these tutorials.

I have a .crt and a .key file.
I have added these files in my `etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` file, I have also enabled `redirect_http_to_https` option and so on.

My server is unning on  Ubuntu 16.04 + Plesk 17.

I appreciate every help :)

Comment: What is the error you get ?

Comment: It doesn't get any response...
When I use http, everything works fine.